# Cannot solve following integral problem.

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem I am stuck with is as follows:

$$\int^\infty_0\frac{\exp(-A\sqrt{e^t-1})}{1 + (e^t-1)B} dt$$

considering $g = \sqrt{e^t-1}$, I get $dg= \frac{e^t}{2\sqrt{e^t-1}}$ and $e^t = g^2-1$

$$\int^\infty_0\frac{\exp(-A\sqrt{e^t-1})}{1 + (e^t-1)B} dt$$

$$\int^\infty_0\frac{2g \ \exp{(-Ag)}}{(g^2-1)(1+g^2B)} dg$$

This the maximum I can get, it still is too complex. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There are two mistakes: 1) $e^t=g^2+1;$ 2) after the change of variables $2g$ is missing. Corect form of the integral is $\int^\infty_0\frac{e^{-Ag}2g}{(1+g^2)(1+Bg^2)}dg.$ It seems that residues should be used to compute it

Comment: Yes that was a typo. Have corrected it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer out of Mathematica which couldn't do it directly, but could after the trick I used below. If
$$
I(A,B)=\int^\infty_0\frac{\exp(-A\sqrt{e^t-1})}{1 + (e^t-1)B} dt
$$

To get the integration to work we can first take a Mellin transform of the integrand with respect to $A$,

$$
\mathcal{M}_A[I(A,B)](s)=\Gamma(s)\int^\infty_0\frac{(e^t-1)^{-s/2}}{1 + (e^t-1)B} dt
$$
this integrates to
$$
\mathcal{M}_A[I(A,B)](s)= \frac{(1-B^{s/2})\pi \csc(\pi s/2)\Gamma(s)}{1-B}
$$
then taking the inverse Mellin transform of both sides 
$$
\mathcal{M}^{-1}[\mathcal{M}_A[I(A,B)](s)](A)= \mathcal{M}^{-1}\left[\frac{(1-B^{s/2})\pi \csc(\pi s/2)\Gamma(s)}{1-B}\right](A)
$$
$$
I(A,B)= \mathcal{M}^{-1}\left[\frac{(1-B^{s/2})\pi \csc(\pi s/2)\Gamma(s)}{1-B}\right](A)
$$

gives the answer
$$
(B-1)I(A,B) = -2 \text{Ci}\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}}\right) \cos \left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}}\right)-2 \text{Si}\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}}\right) \sin \left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}}\right)+\pi\sin
   \left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}}\right)+2 \text{Ci}(A) \cos (A)+2 \text{Si}(A) \sin (A)-\pi  \sin (A)
$$
where $\text{Ci}$ and $\text{Si}$ are the Cos and Sine integral functions.
This expression seems to be correct numerically for various positive values of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Sorry I have heard for Melling transform for the very first time. Can you let me know what is $s$ here?

Comment: sorry, actually after looking into it, I cannot get what the final answer is The solution you have given in the end is the final solution in terms of Melling transofrm of A? This does not seem to be the final soluation given the Transform term inthe notation?

Comment: I gave you the answer first: $(B-1)I(A,B) = -2 \text{Ci}\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}}\right) \cos \left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}}\right)-2 \text{Si}\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}}\right) \sin \left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}}\right)+\pi\sin
   \left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}}\right)+2 \text{Ci}(A) \cos (A)+2 \text{Si}(A) \sin (A)-\pi  \sin (A)$
Sorry I should have written it more clearly. You don't need to understand the final steps if you just need the answer.

Comment: @Kashan The $s$ variable was used in the transform. So we took the problem in terms of $A$, changed it to a problem in terms of $s$ and then converted back to a solution containing $A$. Analogous to the variable change in a Fourier or Laplace transform. I haven't explicitly shown the transforms but you can find them using Google, I just performed them in Mathematica to help it arrive at the solution.

Comment: @Kashan I have rearranged it and added a few more steps, if it is still not clear let me know.